# Zooming into State to view ZipCode using R Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson

I am using R leaftlet package to create a interactive choropleth of the U.S.

There are several tutorials online and I am able to create interactive state level map with popups and zooming. Also I was also able to create a separate zip code level map again with popups.

I would like both views in one map itself but make zip code visible as I zoom in a state or double click on a state. Like If I double click on New York, the New York Zip Code opens up. Is there a package/function in R that can help me do this?

Here are static screenshots of both to make things clear what I plan to integrate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just wonder if [this link](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html) would help you. It seems to me that you would need two layers in order to achieve your goal. If you could crate a layer which shows zip code level map, I think you can make it.

Comment: Yes I thought about using this way. But the problem is the US Zip Code rendered map is huge! If I just create a layer all zip codes for each state have to be rendered using layers. It is like around 7mb and  it is inefficient to upload it on  a website. 

I was wondering if there is way that as soon as I double click on a state it opens another map with zip code for that state.  
That way I only need to render  US State map once and if I person clicks on state it renders zip code level for that state.

Comment: @jazzurro Any help would be greatly appreciate. Or if you can point me to someone/tag who can contribute.  Scott Chamberlain is one of them but SO is not allowing me to tag him.

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot really give you anything more. If you do not want to create a whole zip code map, you may want to allow users to select a state. If you use Shiny, you can allow the users to interactively subset data (choosing a state). That may be one way to go.

Comment: Um, do you have a link/example on how Shiny  allows subsetting by choosing a state? Is it mostly using a dropdown?

Comment: You may want to have a look of shiny gallery (http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/). If users can choose one of the States, you can highlight the state with a colour. You could use the selection to filler the polygon data of the zip code. In this way, you do not make R to draw the whole zip code map.

Comment: Yes I have seen this , are you talking about the SuperZip example?  Also in your recommendation to choose a state by a dropdown?  
I sorry I didn't get your color example. Let's suppose I have  state map as shown with blue shade. Let's suppose I chose New York then I would want map to zoom in to New York zips.    Can you explain your color trick a little further please?

Comment: You want to think how you can use dynamic user interface. You can allow user to choose a state with that. The other thing is that I think you want to explore the two layer option. I do not think you can automatically show the zip level map by simply zooming in. You probably want to make users to choose a state in the interface and draw a zip code level layer on top of the US map. I am simply guess, but this seems to be one way to go.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Yehoshapat Schellekens that in R one might not have the flexibility of a web programming language. But seldom R is not flexible enough to achieve fancy results! :) Here you go with a "vanilla" example of what you basically need. You can customize the windows popup with some JS.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

mapStates = map("state", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
mapCounty = map("county", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(leafletOutput('myMap'),
             br(),
             leafletOutput('myMap2')),

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
          addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                           options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
          addPolygons(lng = mapStates$x, 
                      lat = mapStates$y, 
                      fillColor = topo.colors(10, alpha = NULL), 
                      stroke = FALSE)
  })
 
  observeEvent(input$myMap_shape_click, {
        click <- input$myMap_shape_click
        if(is.null(click))
          return()       
    
    lat <- click$lat
    lon <- click$lng

    coords <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon, lat))
    point <- SpatialPoints(coords)
    mapStates_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(mapStates, IDs = mapStates$names)
    i <- point [mapStates_sp, ]
    selected <- mapStates_sp [i]
    mapCounty_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(mapCounty, IDs = mapCounty$names)
    z <- over(mapCounty_sp, selected)
    r <- mapCounty_sp[(!is.na(z))] 

    output$myMap2 <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>% 
          addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
          addPolygons(data=r,
                      fillColor = topo.colors(10, alpha = NULL), 
                      stroke = FALSE)
    })  
  })
})
```

NOTE: The datasets used in the example seem to have different accuracies (not perfect overlap for states and counties). Therefore the spatial matching is accounting for more counties than expected (those inside plus those intersecting the state borders). Use the name as ID (argument `layerId`) instead to achive the perfect match.

Answer (score 3):

I've created the same type of app working off of G. Cocca's code, and after a few months of fiddling with it over and over, I've come up with a more elegant solution to your problem. For simple reproducibility, I'm using Rwanda shapefiles as an example (because they're much smaller than GADM's USA shapefiles, but you can always just replace these with your own US shapefiles).

```
library(raster)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

#load in shapefiles for state and county level 
states <- getData("GADM", country = "rwa", level = 1)
counties <- getData("GADM", country = "rwa", level = 2)

#define color palettes for states
pal <- brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")
statePal <- colorFactor(pal, states@data$NAME_1)


shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    leafletOutput('myMap', width = "100%"), 
    br(), 
    leafletOutput("myMap2", width = "100%")
  ), #END UI

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    #default state level map output
    output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(data = states, 
                    fillColor = ~statePal(states@data$NAME_1), 
                    fillOpacity = 1, 
                    color = "white", 
                    stroke = T, 
                    weight = 1, 
                    layerId = states@data$NAME_1) #this sets the click id, very important! 
    }) #END RENDERLEAFLET OUTPUT

    observeEvent(input$myMap_shape_click, {

      #define click object
      click <- input$myMap_shape_click

      #subset counties shapefile so that only counties from the clicked state are mapped
      selected <- counties[counties$NAME_1 == click$id,]

      #define color palette for counties 
      countyPal <- colorFactor(pal, selected@data$NAME_2)

      #if click id isn't null (i.e. if ANY polygon is clicked on), draw map of counties
      if(!is.null(click$id)){
        output$myMap2 <- renderLeaflet({
          leaflet() %>% 
            addTiles() %>% 
            addPolygons(data = selected, 
                        fillColor = ~countyPal(selected@data$NAME_2), 
                        fillOpacity = 1, 
                        color = "white", 
                        stroke = T, 
                        weight = 1)
        }) #END RENDERLEAFLET
      } #END CONDITIONAL
    }) #END OBSERVE EVENT 
  }) #END SHINYAPP
```

The first output is your state level map. With this code, when you click on a state of interest, a click object is created that has a `click$id` corresponding the name of that state (which is established in the `layerId` definition in the `addPolygons` call). With the `click$id` as the selected state name, you can then subset your county level polygon by that state and plot it as a map.

The options for designing this map are endless, really. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to create this through R, you need to run this through good old java Script, and specifically leaflet.

Keep in mind that R does not run the map, all it does is to create a java-script template of an HTML file, your Web browser runs the rest (Not R interpreter)

The professional word you are looking for is **event binding**, which on one click will trig both zooming in your original US map, and open a new map of a state with its zip code.

General instructions (this is all java script, no R!):

go to http://leafletjs.com/reference.html and find events, you need the *dblclick* event.

Then you'll need to create a function that opens up a new map.

keep in mind that if you want to do sophisticated stuff, R will give you very limited solutions, so my advice is when you need nice java script visualizations just go straight to the source :)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement needs lot of customization. If you are good in JavaScript just check [geojson2svg](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg) that gives lot of flexibility. Basically it converts GeoJSON to SVG, that's all then rest you can achieve with plain HTML and JavaScript. Here are some [examples](http://maps-on-blackboard.com/tag/geojson2svg/).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  I didnt quite understand it.
I am good with Javascript and already using GeoJSON but how can I integrate SVG?

Comment: If the purpose is for data visualization not navigation then if you convert GeoJSON to SVG it gives lot of flexibility for handle the SVG. Styling can be achieved with CSS and interaction can be handled with any event handling library like jQuery or Hammer.js. Just check this example http://maps-on-blackboard.com/articles/interactive-map/