# Zoomable/clickable leaflet map to zoom in on specific geolocation

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to make a leaflet plot clickable and zoomable in R.

I have data on some geographical locations like in the image below:

[image]

If I were to click on the "province" of Madrid I would like to make the leaflet map zoom in on this area and show the "municipalities" of Madrid in the map.

[image]

How can I store the users selection of "provincias" and filter the "municipias"

Code:

```
library(mapSpain)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

provincias <- mapSpain::esp_get_prov() %>%
  sf::st_transform(provincias, crs = 4326)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  addPolygons(data = provincias)

# once the province has been selected, we filter and zoom in on the area
mad = mapSpain::esp_get_munic() %>% 
  sf::st_transform(provincias, crs = 4326) %>% 
  filter(ine.ccaa.name == "Madrid, Comunidad de")

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  addPolygons(data = mad)
```

Comment: As far as I know you need Shiny to accomplish this task

Comment: Yes, my intention was to implement the leaflet plot into a shiny App and use `input$clickLocation` as the inputs to the `filter` function.

Comment: I see.. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216819/zooming-into-state-to-view-zipcode-using-r-leaflet/32468096#32468096